# macports not installing packages such as moria

Tags: macports

I've recently installed macports as I'm interested in development, and I've tried to install a game such as moria as my first item and it doesn't work.

Here is the piece of code I tried using:

```
sudo ports install moria
```

and as an output return I got the following:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for moria
--->  Fetching archive for moria
--->  Attempting to fetch moria-5.5.2_5.darwin_22.arm64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/moria
--->  Attempting to fetch moria-5.5.2_5.darwin_22.arm64.tbz2 from https://kmq.jp.packages.macports.org/moria
--->  Attempting to fetch moria-5.5.2_5.darwin_22.arm64.tbz2 from https://pek.cn.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/moria
--->  Building moria
Warning: reinplace s|/home/math/grabiner/moria/files|/opt/local/var/games/moria| didn't change anything in /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_games_moria/moria/work/umoria/source/config.h
Error: Failed to build moria: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_games_moria/moria/main.log for details.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets if you believe there
is a bug.
Error: Processing of port moria failed
```

I've been to the documentation website and tried

```
sudo ports clean
```

but then it shows up with:

> Can't map the URL 'file://.' to a port description file ("Could not find Portfile in /Users/*username*").
> Please verify that the directory and portfile syntax are correct.
> To use the current port, you must be in a port's directory.

Answer (score 0):

See:

https://ports.macports.org/port/moria/details/

It appears moria does not build on recent macOS versions and that upstream is dead.  If you can find an updated version, please raise a bug report on MacPorts.